# How do I DRY up this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

Here is the code:

```
when 'jty'
 if j.type != "0"
  @color = allColors.find { |c| c['type'] == j.type.to_s }
   clr << @color.color if @color
 else
   clr << @@default_map_marker_color
 end             
when 'jcat'
  if j.priority != "0"
    @color = allColors.find { |c| c['type'] == j.priority.to_s }
    clr << @color.color if @color
  else
    clr << @@default_map_marker_color
  end
```

I have six more `when` statements in this case, and I repeat this part:

```
clr << @color.color if @color
```

over and over.  I hate it.

Here are some things you need to know:

`clr` is an empty array that I initialize outside the `case` statement, and the `case` statement is inside a `for` loop that's going through a lot of objects.  It's basically looking up the color associated with a particular thing, and this is my NoSQL-hack-ish way to get relational data.

If I just do something like:

```
def push_color
 clr << @color.color if @color
end
```

`clr` and `@color` aren't being passed around without params for the method.  There's something I just dislike about passing params to all my methods - it's too dependent.  I'm stretching to understand this better and write code that doesn't have these implicit dependencies.  Sometimes I have to pass info from one method to another, but it creates a dependency that breaks everything if that param I'm passing changes or disappears, and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

I don't understand how I can just get `clr` to be filled with WHATEVER returns from the `case` statement.  Ideally it would be something like:

```
clr = pref.map do |p|
 p(&:do_the_switch_statement_here)
end
```

and `p` would be the entire case and we would just return something.

That's where my head is, but I can't quite imagine how.

Comment: Why not use `collect`?

Comment: could you post your full method? and what `jcat` and `jty` in terms of the case statement?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and belongs on [codereview.se] 
because it is about improving existing code, not fixing broken code.

Comment: Do not use the symbol `type` as the name of a method or other property.  This is a reserved term, and causes unexpected behavior in some circumstances

Comment: Here are a couple of simple things you can do. 1. Write `clr << case xx`.  2. Though less efficient, writing `when jcat && j.priority != "0"`, `when jcat && j.priority == "0"` might be clearer and less prone to error than `when jcat` `if j.priority != "0"...else...end`.  I would be surprised if this question is not closed, for the reason given by @theTinMan.  I encourage you to put it on Code Review, but if you do, please include more code.

Answer (score -1):

Your current code has duplications, for instance:

`j.type` versus `j.priority` but both times you check that the
value is not string '0'.

Later on you again use the same method. This seems superfluous.

On top of that you use a class variable when there is no need
for it. I recommend to not use class variables.

It is not a good code to start wanting to optimize it at all.

Your data structures are needlessly complicated.

When you simplify all your data structures, the code will
almost automagically become much much simpler.

Comment: You haven't added a single example of anything that I can do to improve the code.